# Missing makefile in the /lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/basic/ directory

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I encountered **invalid kernel configuration** issue when trying to build a kernel module. I followed its error message to run **make oldconfig** and I got another error caused by a missing make file in the **/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/basic/** directory. Does anyone knows what makefile it referred to? My debian is **12.1.0** and its kernel is **6.1.0-10-amd64**.

I tried to execute the Makefile with oldconfig parameter in the linux-headers folder (/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-10-common) and it prompted the error above.

Comment: You may use "linux-headers" package only for **building modules** against the kernel which is already built. With that package you cannot rebuild the kernel itself, that is why the package doesn't support `make oldconfig`. If you want to rebuild the entire kernel, you need to install a package with **source files**.

Comment: I wasn't building kernel but a module. Theoretically the headers supplied by any distro should be sufficient for building modules. The problem I encountered above was due to the missing .config (kernel configuration file) and it can only be generated with complete kernel source tree. Anyway, I have solved my problem above by building and installing a new kernel.

Comment: "Linux headers" package should contain the `.config` file for which the kernel has been configured. If that file is absent, then the package is broken. Generating another `.config` file (like you do with `make oldconfig`) for such package has a little sense: a new config file will differ from the config file the kernel has been built against, so any module which will be compiled using that new config file with be **incompatible** with the kernel. Probably, your interpretation of the error message about `make oldconfig` was wrong.

Comment: That's ok. I am using the new kernel now and I think all the modules build from its config file should be ok. Thank you for your help.